# Merge select box selects values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 select boxes and one input.

I need to merge the selected values together and add it to the hidden input box.

For example:

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
            <option value="1-">1</option>
</select>

<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-2">
            <option value="5-">5</option>
</select>

<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-3">
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
```

Finally I want to get:

Is this case the value would be:

1-5-2011

How could I get this functionality togehter please?

Comment: When do you need to do it? When the selected values change? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/TvDP2/23/)

one way to do it is:

HTML:

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option value="1-">1</option>
    <option value="2-">2</option>
    <option value="3-">3</option>
</select>

<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-2">
    <option value="5-">5</option>
    <option value="6-">6</option>
    <option value="7-">7</option>
</select>

<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-3">
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' id='myhidden' value='' />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            var myele = '';
            $.each($('select option:selected'), function() {
                myele += $(this).val();
            });
            $('#myhidden').val(myele);
            console.log($('#myhidden').val());
        });
    });
   }); 
</script>
```

Modified w/ onchange.

Comment: Where about in my html page do a add the script to?

Comment: @satch you can do a on document ready within your `<head></head>` tag but make sure you use the `<script type='text/javascript'>code here</script>`

Comment: I am having problems here. I need #myhidden value is not returning the selected value of each selectbox but all of it. All 3 select boxes have more than one option but I need it to only get the selected option. Currently it's getting all of the 3 of them into 1.

Comment: @satch ic what you are trying to do now.  please check the edited answer.

Comment: Ref: create a button and attach an onclick event = more stuff to be done by user. Can't it use onchange event ?

Comment: @satch sure, my example just a demo.  you can attach whatever onchange you want, but in your case would you have to attach onchange on all three select drop downs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the code to be flexible enough to work with an arbitrary number of `<select>` elements, you can write something like:

```
$("#yourInputBoxId").val($("[id^=select-choice-]").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(""));
```

Here, [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) will project into an array the selected values of all the `<select>` elements whose `id` attributes begin with `select-choice-`. The array items are then concatenated into a string, without a separator (since the values already contain one).

Comment: +1 Well this is just great! Especially added into a .change() function! nice

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#id_of_hidden_input" ).val( 
    $( "#select-choice-1" ).val() + 
    $( "#select-choice-2" ).val() + 
    $( "#select-choice-3" ).val()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you get always use php by POST or get

change the names

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
            <option value="1-">1</option>
</select>

<select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">
            <option value="5-">5</option>
</select>

<select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3">
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>


$choice1 = $_POST['select-choice-1'];
$choice2 = $_POST['select-choice-2'];
$choice3 = $_POST['select-choice-3'];
echo $choice ."-".$choice2 ."-".$choice3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the selectedIndex and options properties of the select element. Here is a quick example:

```
var elm1 = document.getElementById("select-choice-1"),
    elm2 = document.getElementById("select-choice-2"),
    elm3 = document.getElementById("select-choice-3"),
    sel1 = elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value,
    sel2 = elm2.options[elm2.selectedIndex].value,
    sel3 = elm3.options[elm3.selectedIndex].value;
alert( sel1 + sel2 + sel3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var $selects = $('#select_box_1,#select_box_2,#select_box_3');
    var seperator = '-';

    $selects.change(function() {
      var val = [];
      $selects.each(function() {
        val.push($(this).val());
      });

      $('#hidden_input').val(val.join(seperator));
    }).trigger('change');
```

This allows for any number of selectbox values to be concatinated with a seperator of your choice.
The `.trigger('change);` causes the bound `.change(...)` event to fire and concatinate the values on page load (just in case the form ha been submitted and the selectboxes prefilled)